# How to view synonym procedure in sql developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a procedure, function synonym from production environment.
When i search with name in sql developer it shows in a list, but when i click to view it just show CREATE synonym statement only not a code. But in TOAD it will show by pressing F4 key i think.

How i able to view that synonym procedure in SQL developer tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place your cursor on the syn name in your pl/sql block.

Right click, Popup DESC

This will open the underlying PL/SQL program, in this case, a procedure in my schema.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @thatjeffsmith